# Proxy Settings Wildfly

Tags: jboss, liferay, wildfly

I've a Wildfly 10 application server with an instance of Liferay 6.2 running on it and I've been trying to properly set the proxy settings. However all portlets requiring a external internet connection experience a time out

In the standalone.conf file I added the following line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=[myhost]-Dhttp.proxyPort=[myport]"
```

and in then standalone.xml I've added the following two properties to the system-properties-attribute.

```
<property name="http.proxyHost" value="[myhost]"/>
<property name="http.proxyPort" value="[myport]"/>
```

I've also checked that the server's os is connected to the internet.

Does anyone know as to why this is not working?

Kind regards,
John

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?