# Proxy Configuration for Liferay Portal CE 7

Tags: configuration-files, http-proxy, wildfly-10, liferay-7

I have a question about the proxy configuration for Liferay Portal 7 CE. I have searched for quite a while, but haven’t found anything really helpful on the subject. There is already a question here on stackoverflow related to Liferay’s proxy configuration in Wildfly, but it has not been answered yet: [Proxy Settings Wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346653/proxy-settings-wildfly)

We use a squid proxy server for internet access (no authentication, just a proxy port and a host for HTTP and HTTPs). I would like to run Liferay portal on my local machine and therefore need to tell the portal to use the proxy for web access.

How do I do this? Do I make changes to

a)  Liferay’s configuration files (i.e., the portal-ext.properties, I guess) or do I change

b)  the configuration files of the application server, on which the portal is running on, or

c)  change the configuration for the portlets (e.g. for the marketplace portlet)?

What options would I have to set in the respective configuration files?

Best regards,

Felix

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - this question is on administering/configuration, not related to programming. You'll be more likely to find help for this question in the Liferay forums. There, such a question will be on topic. Please consider to delete the question here and bring it over to the Liferay forums

Answer (score 1):

Proxy configuration is splitted in two configuration files: system-ext.properties and portal-ext.properties.

In **system-ext.properties** you have to configure the proxy environment configuration settings that affects to whole JVM process:

> ```
> http.proxyHost=192.168.0.200
> http.proxyPort=4480
> ```

You have to create **system-ext.properties** file inside webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes. (inside Liferay application classloader)
You have more information about system-ext proxy settings in following link: https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/propertiesdoc/system.properties.html#HTTP

In **portal-ext.properties** you have to configure the proxy environment configuration settings that affects only to Liferay portal:

> ```
> com.liferay.portal.util.HttpImpl.proxy.username=
> com.liferay.portal.util.HttpImpl.proxy.password=
> ```

You have more information about portal-ext proxy settings in following link: https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#HTTP

If your proxy has no authentication, only **system-ext.properties** settings are necessary